# Query regarding type of room while booking

Tags: france, bookings, hotels, accommodation

So I was planning to book a room for a night at La Colle Sur Loup, France. While in conversation with the hotel authorities, they said something like this:

> we have a room without restauration at 83 euros

What does restauration mean? What does this statement mean?

Comment: Maybe they mean restaurant (breakfast or dinner). Which would mean you would not get any food there for that €83?

Comment: no breakfast included ?

Comment: it simply means "food", as you can instantly see from any dictionary or translation site.  you may be familiar with the English word "restaurant" - it simply comes from that French word.

Answer (score 5):

Restauration means catering. This means that you won't get any meal with the night.

Usually, you can have the following :

- Breakfast (petit déjeuner in French)
- Half board (demi pension in French, which usually mean that you have lunch or diner included)
- Full board (pension complète in French, which means that you have breakfast, lunch and diner included)

So in that case, I think they used "restauration" as a poor direct translation to express the fact that there is no meal included. So probably, the breakfast is also excluded. If you provide the hotel name, I can check the french part and tell you for sure.

Comment: Belambra club La Bergerie

Comment: on the french website, I see two packages : one half board and one without any meal (because there is a kitchen in the room).

Answer (score 1):

It means 'without food'. So either they don't have food or you would pay extra if you ate there.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=translate+sans+restauration